# Oracle 12c - I cannot modify constraint of column ORA-02275

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I create a table ASSIGNMENTS:

```
CREATE TABLE assignments (
    id_project NUMBER(4) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_assignments_01 REFERENCES projects (id_project),
    empl_number NUMBER(6) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_assignments_02 REFERENCES employees (empl_id),
    start DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    end DATE,
        CONSTRAINT chk_assignements_dates CHECK (end > start),
    rate NUMBER(7, 2),
        CONSTRAINT chk_assignements_rate CHECK (rate > 0),
    role VARCHAR2(20),
        CONSTRAINT chk_assignements_role CHECK (rola IN ('ANALYST', 'DEVELOPER'))
);
```

And now I have to modify constraint fk_assignments_02. I want to set fk_assignments_02 ON DELETE CASCADE. I tried do it as following:

```
ALTER TABLE assignments
    MODIFY id_project NUMBER(4) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_assignments_01 REFERENCES projects (id_project) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But I get an error:
ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

Comment: Drop the constraint first and then re-create it.

Comment: I want to know how to modify it, I don't want re-create table. It's not a solution, it's a hack.

Comment: Were you able to create the table with that statement? I strongly doubt it. You have a typo: in the last check constraint, `rola IN ...` - the name of the column is `role`, not `rola`. `start` is an Oracle reserved word, so it can't be used as a column name. What's the problem, is COPY AND PASTE broken on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that - you'll have to drop and re-add the constraint. There is no provision in Oracle to change the `ON DELETE` action, which is part of the `REFERENCES` clause rather than being part of the constraint state.

So to accomplish this you'd need to do

```
ALTER TABLE ASSIGNMENTS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ASSIGNMENTS_02;
```

followed by

```
ALTER TABLE ASSIGNMENTS
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ASSIGNMENTS_02
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROJECT) REFERENCES PROJECT (ID_PROJECT)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Best of luck.